# 'Enviroment' is not declared?

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I'm using SharpDevelop 4.4.2 on a Windows 8.1 Update 1 computer, and on a Visual Basic Windows Form, and I'm trying to retrieve the operating system's name/info but when I use this code:

```
Private Sub button1Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim major As Integer = Enviroment.OSVersion.Version.major
    Dim minor As Integer = Enviroment.OSVersion.Version.minor
    If major = 5 And minor = 2 Then
        Me.Label2.Text = "Operating System: Windows XP"
    ElseIf major = 6 And minor = 0 Then
        Me.Label2.Text = "Operating System: Windows Vista"
    ElseIf major = 6 And minor = 1 Then
        Me.label2.Text = "Operating System: Windows 7"
    End If
End Sub
```

; it gives this error in the output:

```
Dim major As Integer = Enviroment.OSVersion.Version.major
Dim major As Integer = Enviroment.OSVersion.Version.minor
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have an `Imports System` line?

Comment: Spell it correctly - `Environment`

Comment: I'm so dumb.... thanks alot guys.